# 2D dynamic arrays / lists syntax question

Tags: c#, list, matrix, grid

I'm trying to create a dynamic 2d array in c#. I'm thinking to use a list of lists such that

```
List<List<int>> grid = new List<List<int>>();
```

How do I populate the grid, i tried using

```
  grid = 
        {
          { 1,3,5,7,9},
          { 2,4,6,8,10},
          { 3,5,7,9,11},
          { 4,6,8,10,12},
          { 5,7,9,11,13}

        };
```

but that didn't work.
I found that I can add individual items such that

```
grid[0][0] = 1;
```

I don't want to use nested loop to fill the grid this way though. I just want to set the grid in one line. Is that possible?

Comment: That's not a 2d array. A 2d array is declared as `int[,]`. It's closer to a jagged array (an array of arrays) which would be declared as `int[][]`, but you're working with lists so you have a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [collection initialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), which is very similar to your first attempt. You just need the type names before each curly brace:

```
List<List<int>> grid = new List<List<int>> {
        new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
```

However, `List<List<int>>` might not be the best way to represent a "grid", because you can easily add an element to, say, the first row:

```
grid[0].Add(1);
```

And suddenly your `grid` ceases to be a grid.

You could consider using an `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<int>>` if your grid is constant. If you still want to set the grid values, you can use a `int[,]` instead:

```
int[,] grid = {
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0},
    };
```

Comment: one question does it matter if I put () at the end? IT seems to compile both ways
 List<List<int>> grid = new List<List<int>> (){...}